# Local terms sets migration issue

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, migration

In a migration process from 2010 to 2013, I success to export/import my bank of terms with a backup/restore way but all of the local terms sets (**those set on each site collection**) are not included.

For each site collection, I lose the local store.

Did you know why and how can I fix it, please?

Comment: Did you migrated the Service Application DB and joined with SharePoint 2013 Service Application?